# Haskell Datagram UDP Sockets: Receiving works but sending doesn't

Tags: sockets, haskell, udp

For understanding how network communication works in Haskell, I am implementing an echo-like simple UDP server.
It is supposed to listen via IPv6 on localhost (port 7331), receive messages and echo them back to the sender concatenated with another string.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Network.Socket hiding (send, sendTo, recv, recvFrom)
import Network.Socket.ByteString
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Exception
import Control.Monad (forever)
import System.IO (
        IOMode (ReadWriteMode)
        , hPutStrLn
                 )
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS

main = do
    sock <- socket AF_INET6 Datagram defaultProtocol
    let hints = defaultHints { addrFamily = AF_INET6, addrSocketType = Datagram}
    serverAddr <- addrAddress . head <$> getAddrInfo (Just hints) (Just "::1") (Just "7331")
    print serverAddr
    bind sock serverAddr
    print sock
    forever $ do
        receivedStuff <- recvFrom sock 65535    -- blocks
        forkIO $ bracket newSendSocket close (serveReceive receivedStuff)

serveReceive :: (BS.ByteString, SockAddr) -> Socket -> IO ()
serveReceive (msg, fromAddr) sendSocket = do
    putStrLn $ "Got message " ++ show msg ++ " from " ++ show fromAddr
    sendTo sendSocket ("Hi, thx for " `BS.append` msg) fromAddr
    putStrLn "sent response"
    return ()

newSendSocket :: IO Socket
newSendSocket = socket AF_INET6 Datagram defaultProtocol
```

I am testing the server's functionality using netcat: `nc -u -6 "localhost" 7331`

The server receives the messages and is able to putStrLn them to stdout. But the responses never show up in netcat.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? As far as I know Datagram sockets do not need to be bound (`bind`) or `connect`ed before sending data using `sendTo`.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you opening up a new socket for sending?  That isn't necessary.  If you just re-use your existing socket then things work fine.  Alternatively we can use wireshark and look.

**Using a new socket for response (the code posted in question)**

The `sendTo` return value suggests the right number of bytes are sent.  Looking at wire shark we see the response on the wire but the response is then rejected with an ICMP Destination Port Unreachable (nc isn't accepting messages from other ports).

**Using the original socket***

If we don't create a socket specifically for the response, and instead just re-use the original socket, then things operation as you'd expect - just fine.

Comment: > Why are you opening up a new socket for sending?

The reason for that is that I want to fork parsing, processing and replying of messages into their own threads to be able to process many messages concurrently.
The documentation of Network.Socket notes:
>The proper programming model is that one Socket is handled by a single thread. If multiple threads use one Socket concurrently, unexpected things would happen.

So at least I cannot pass the socket to multiple threads at a time. Always creating a new receiving socket and binding it is probably a bad idea as well.

Comment: So I either need another option for concurrently sending replies independent from the receiving thread, or need to figure out whether it is possible to circumvent the ICMP Destination Port Unreachable errors in a real client implementation.
Still thanks so far, maybe you have some experience with concurrently processing UDP packets. Most examples I find deal with TCP, which is easier to handle.

Comment: Probably the way to go here is to only use unconnected datagram sockets. I cannot test the program with netcat then, but I'm writing the corresponding client myself anyways.

`man 2 connect`:
> If the socket sockfd is of type SOCK_DGRAM, then addr is the address to which datagrams are sent by default, and the only address from which  datagrams  are  received.

Comment: The note in the documentation looks like nonsense to me.  I would speculate that it was written with TCP connections in mind and refers to the rather obvious problems of having multiple threads reading and/or writing from a stream.  Looking through the `Network.Socket` source, I see no problem with multiple threads sending concurrent messages over the same UDP socket with `sendTo`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, maybe I should make my comment an answer, in case someone is able to make a case that `Network.Socket` *isn't* thread-safe and can follow up with some convincing comments.

The `Network.Socket` module is a thin layer around the usual [Berkeley sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) API.  For Berkeley sockets, there's no problem using a single UDP socket with multiple threads making concurrent `recvFrom` or `sendTo` calls or both.  For UDP connections, the socket itself is largely stateless, except for the local IP address and port to which it's been bound.  Specifically, the `recvFrom` and `sendTo` calls are fundamentally "atomic" for UDP -- there's no way two simultaneous outgoing datagrams would get "interleaved", and there's no way an incoming datagram would get divided up into small chunks between threads.

The UDP protocol doesn't guarantee that all packets will be delivered, and it doesn't guarantee they won't be duplicated, so your application needs to be prepared for a (whole, complete) datagram to be delivered to more than one thread or to zero threads, but that has nothing to do with thread safety.  That's just UDP.

If `Network.Socket` added a buffering layer or some other complex processing, then it's possible it might not be thread safe, even for UDP, but looking at the code, I see `recvFrom` and `sendTo` doing nothing more than memory allocation and the equivalent socket C calls.

Given this, the most reasonable architecture for a multithreaded UDP echo server is to use a single receiving thread that unconditionally dispatches a new thread for each request.  You probably wouldn't use this architecture in a C program with pthreads, because those threads are pretty expensive if you're handling lots of requests, but GHC `forkIO` threads are lightweight, so forking, say, several thousand of those shouldn't be an issue.

```
module Main where

import Network.Socket hiding (recvFrom, sendTo)
import Network.Socket.ByteString
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  sock <- socket AF_INET6 Datagram defaultProtocol
  addr:_ <- getAddrInfo (Just defaultHints
                          { addrFamily = AF_INET6, addrSocketType = Datagram })
                        (Just "::1") (Just "7331")
  bind sock (addrAddress addr)
  forever $ do
    result <- recvFrom sock 4096
    forkIO $ worker sock result

worker :: Socket -> (ByteString, SockAddr) -> IO ()
worker sock (msg, client) = do
  threadDelay 1000000   -- simulate some processing
  void $ sendTo sock msg client
```

In my original answer, in addition to the approach above, I had suggested an alternative architecture using a fixed number of worker threads in a recv-send loop, like so:

```
import Network.Socket hiding (recvFrom, sendTo)
import Network.Socket.ByteString
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad

main :: IO ()
main = do
  sock <- socket AF_INET6 Datagram defaultProtocol
  addr:_ <- getAddrInfo (Just defaultHints
                          { addrFamily = AF_INET6, addrSocketType = Datagram })
                        (Just "::1") (Just "7331")
  bind sock (addrAddress addr)
  replicateM_ 16 $ forkIO $ worker sock
  forever $ threadDelay longtime
  where longtime = 10^12

worker :: Socket -> IO ()
worker sock = forever $ do
  (msg, client) <- recvFrom sock 4096
  threadDelay 1000000   -- simulate some processing
  sendTo sock msg client
```

The advantage of this is that, even if a lot of requests come in simultaneously, there's a pre-specified upper bound on the number of simultaneous workers that will be running.  (The actual upper limit for a "surge" of requests before they start getting dropped will be higher than the number of workers, as the O/S will buffer packets even if all workers are occupied.)  One disadvantage, pointed out by upstream, is that all the Haskell threads (in the above example, 16 of them) get woken up resulting in a bunch of `recvFrom` calls, only one of which gets a response.  However, the whole point of using this approach is to limit the number of simultaneous requests, so we're not in a context where a few dozen extra system calls matters.

The fact remains that, with either approach, there is no thread safety problem operating over a single socket.

Comment: Thanks, your explanations do indeed make sense. I'll probably open an upstream issue for clarification.
But what would be the drawbacks of playing safe and creating a new unconnected Datagram socket for each sending thread? As long as I don't `connect` a socket, it should accept packets from all source addresses. And as I am writing both client and server, I can make them use unconnected sockets.

Or will the creation of so many transient sockets cause to many expensive context switches?

Comment: Upstream issue: https://github.com/haskell/network/issues/444

Comment: The main drawbacks will be poorer performance from the overhead of creating and destroying sockets, as well as the potential to run out of file descriptors under load.  Because you'll be responding from random ports, you may also have trouble working across firewalls or where NAT is in place (uncommon for IPv6, but not unheard of), if you ever move beyond the loopback interface.

Comment: According to upstream, having multiple threads blocking on the same socket requires them to be woken up all at once by the IO manager, resulting in poor performance.
So the documentation remarks are not cause by thread unsafety but by thread performance degradation.

>Yes send, sendTo, recv and recvFrom are thread-safe, but, given the IO-manager glue, racing multiple threads to read from the same socket performs poorly. You get much better results with ReusePort (on servers).

https://github.com/haskell/network/issues/444#issuecomment-612574209

Comment: I have updated my answer based on upstream's comments.